# Cannot configure debugger for c++ on VSCode, using WSL on windows "

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been doing some C++ coding on VSCode. I'm using a Linux environment in a Windows computer using WSL. I can open a linux terminal on VScode, and compile and run C++ files using g++, no problem. However, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to run the debugger. I keep getting:

"ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". The program "..." has exited with code 42 (0x0000002a)."

I looked at the tutorial on the VScode website. What I'm doing is click Run-> Add configuration.

The I get the launch.json file. There is replace program with the path to my executable file I want to debug (this is correct, right?). Then I click: Run or debug -> run c/c++ file. Then I can choose: gcc, g++ or g++-11. Whichever one I choose (seems to make no difference), it sets off a few things in the terminal, then a tasks.json and settings.json get created automatically. and finally I get:

"ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1."

These are the launch and task json files:

launch.json

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
   // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
   // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
      {
         "name": "(gdb) Launch",
         "type": "cppdbg",
         "request": "launch",
         "program": "/mnt/c/C++_TESTS/linuxtest/hello", //This is the path to my executable
         "args": [],
         "stopAtEntry": false,
         "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
         "environment": [],
         "externalConsole": false,
         "MIMode": "gdb",
         "setupCommands": [
             {
                 "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                 "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                 "ignoreFailures": true
             },
             {
                 "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                 "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                 "ignoreFailures": true
             }
         ]
      }

   ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
   "tasks": [
      {
         "type": "cppbuild",
         "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
         "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
         "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
         ],
         "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
         },
         "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
         ],
         "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
         },
         "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
      }
   ],
   "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

settings.json

```
{
   "files.associations": {
      "*.tcc": "cpp",
      "cctype": "cpp",
      "clocale": "cpp",
      "cmath": "cpp",
      "compare": "cpp",
      "concepts": "cpp",
      "cstdint": "cpp",
      "cstdio": "cpp",
      "cstdlib": "cpp",
      "cwchar": "cpp",
      "cwctype": "cpp",
      "exception": "cpp",
      "initializer_list": "cpp",
      "iosfwd": "cpp",
      "iostream": "cpp",
      "istream": "cpp",
      "limits": "cpp",
      "new": "cpp",
      "numbers": "cpp",
      "ostream": "cpp",
      "stdexcept": "cpp",
      "streambuf": "cpp",
      "string": "cpp",
      "string_view": "cpp",
      "system_error": "cpp",
      "type_traits": "cpp",
      "typeinfo": "cpp"
   }
}
```

I have no idea of what I should try or how to fix this, despite searching for a few days and trying different things. I would appreciate any help.

I tried selecting different options between g++, gcc, and gdb. They all give the same error. I checked and all of gcc, g++ and gdb seem to be installed.

Comment: Can you run gdb manually?

Comment: Just to be honest, I'm not sure what that would mean. How does one run gdb manually?

Comment: `gdb ./your_program`

Comment: Yes, I can run that from the command line. I get a whole menu and "Reading symbols from ./program..."

Comment: Is that the same gdb you're using in VScode?

Comment: I'm not sure. I apologize, because I'm new to this stuff. What would be the best way of checking if it's the same one being used in VScode?

Comment: It’s hard to tell if 1) the Linux environment is properly configured and 2) whether VS Code is properly configured to use it from this question. You need the WSL extension and the C++ extension needs to be installed **in** the WSL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did install the WSL extension, and it appears under the "Local-installed" section. It says "This extension is enabled globally".

I also have the C++ extension, which appears two times. Once under Local, and also under  "WSL: UBUNTU". If I hover over each they say: "This extension is enabled globally" and "Extension is enabled on WSL: Ubuntu", respectively.

Comment: check out https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-makefile-tools/issues/378 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7706 and see if either helps you. also https://stackoverflow.com/q/70698730/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/60923232/11107541